# How to make a visual representation of a number

Tags: html, css, html-table, graphics

How can I make that in an HTML table there could be a visual representation (icons/emojis/images) of a number that is given?
I know I can just copy and paste 5 images, but I have to do it automatically somehow.
I have a hint that it's somehow related to background images.
Below is an example.
I'm writing in HTML with all style attributes in the header.

*EDIT*. Thanks. Managed to finish it. Thank you for the help :)

[image: The example]

Comment: is it svg img ?  please add you thml for this , read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You can't *count* smth via HTML, do it via Javascript!

Comment: tell me what's wrong with my answer, did I guess correctly the code you didn't show? , or not ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with utf8 character and String.repeat method

```js
const scores =
  [ { name: 'Janis',   score:  4 }
  , { name: 'Peteris', score:  5 }
  , { name: 'Mikelis', score:  7 }
  , { name: 'Anna',    score:  4 }
  , { name: 'MArija',  score:  5 }
  , { name: 'Katrina', score:  8 }
  , { name: 'Luize',   score: 10 }
  ]
  , myTable = document.getElementById('my-table')
  , chrStar = '\u2b50'
  ;
scores.forEach(({name,score})=>
  {
  let row = myTable.insertRow()
  row.insertCell().textContent = '.'
  row.insertCell().textContent = name
  row.insertCell().textContent = score
  row.insertCell().textContent = chrStar.repeat(score)
  })
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: .5em;
  counter-reset: noElm;
  }
tr {
  counter-increment: noElm;
}
tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
td:nth-of-type(1):before {
  content: counter(noElm);
  }
td {
  padding: .2em .7em;
  /*border: 1px solid black; */
  }
td:nth-of-type(3) {
  text-align: right;
  }
```

```html
<table id="my-table"></table>
```